# sideEffects in antd package.json not working as expected

Tags: css, webpack, antd, tree-shaking, webpack-production

We are using *lib/styles/.css* file from *antd/lib* in one our project files. In production build same is not shipped even when *antd/package.json* defines files at provided location to be sideEffects.

We have tried to set *sideEffects: true* for all CSS files being picked up from node_modules for CSSLoader in Webpack config's *module.rules*.

Import statement-

```
import 'antd/lib/grid/style/index.css';
```

sideEffects definition in *antd/package.json*

```
[
  "dist/*",
  "es/**/style/*",
  "lib/**/style/*",
  "*.less",
]
```

CSSLoader Rules defined as part of our effort to mark required file as sideEffects-

```
{
  include: [/node_modules/],
  sideEffects: true,
}
```

The CSS file imported from *antd* is not present in production bundles.

P.S. No error message is displayed